# Can not observe TraceId & SpanId in Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am trying to run Spring Cloud Sleuth and observe traceid, span id oin logs.

I have configured as below but when i call a requesti cnat see any traceId or logId in logs.

Is there anyone help with this. Thanks.

```
2020-12-02 11:40:02 [main] INFO  az.iba.ms.chasis.ChasisApplication - Started ChasisApplication in 21.425 seconds (JVM running for 23.816)
2020-12-02 11:40:03 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.31.109.104] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/chasis-ms] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-02 11:40:03 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.31.109.104] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-02 11:40:03 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.31.109.104] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 24 ms
2020-12-02 11:40:17 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO  a.i.m.c.controller.ChasisController - Request {}helloChasis from chasis-ms
```

build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-zipkin', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
```

Controller.java

```
package az.iba.ms.chasis.controller;

import az.iba.ms.chasis.entity.Chasis;
import az.iba.ms.chasis.logger.MainLogger;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1")
@Log4j2
@Api(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, tags = "Chasis microservice")
public class ChasisController {

    private static final MainLogger LOGGER = MainLogger.getLogger(ChasisController.class);

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChasisController.class);


    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @ApiOperation(value = "View a list of accounts for given CIF list", response = Chasis.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved message"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource is not found")}
    )
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloChasis() {
        LOG.info("Request {}" + "helloChasis from chasis-ms");
        return "Greetings from Chasis";
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set the sampler probability to 1.0 to ensure that your endpoint gets sampled? You could try sending 10 requests to see that 1 of them is actually traced. We describe this behaviour in the documentation.

Comment: I have changed setting to sleuth.sampler.probability: 1.0  but none of the logs changed

Comment: I don't see your code - what you're doing is absolutely basic stuff so that has to work fine. Maybe you've changed the logging format, maybe you have a mismatch of dependencies (I already see that instead of a BOM you're using hardcoded versions). If you go to start.spring.io, generate a fresh project with sleuth on the classpath things will work out of the box.

Comment: Hey @MarcinGrzejszczak I asked similar  question, I have my config file there but still have same problem as user that asked this question. You can check my question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688048/cant-see-traceid-and-spanid-in-log-for-sleuth

Answer (score 2):

In the new **Spring Cloud Sleuth 3.1**, the API is migrated from Sleuth to Micrometer Tracing. So even in sprint initializr, you will see zipkin and micrometer dependencies (not Sleuth).

Read the [official migration guide](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide).

To enable tracing and Zipkin ready in a distributed system, You must have:

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=microservice1
logging.pattern.level="%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

**MyController.java**

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @Bean
    public Sampler alwaysSampler() {
        return Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE;
    }

    @GetMapping("/microservice1")
    public String method1(){
        logger.info("in method1");
        logger.info("out of method1");
        return "hellooooo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I need to guess, this is caused by some custom Log4J settings you have, more precisely your Log4J pattern (I don't see them so I'm just guessing). Spring Cloud Sleuth [relies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/#features) on log patterns that is [setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-logging) by Spring Boot out of the box (see: [logging config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging)).

I suggest you to give it a try and use the default config first and if it works, you can customize the [default pattern](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml#L7) (I don't recommend customizing it, the defaults are pretty good).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add configuration to let your log-provider know that you want to log these additional fields. Sample logback.xml should look like following:-

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- encoders are assigned the type
ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} traceId: %X{traceId} spanId: %X{spanId} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Spring-cloud sleuth automatically adds the properties traceId and spanId in the MDC of the log-provider you are using