# Can't see traceId and spanId in log for Sleuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud-sleuth

I've started learning Sleuth and I'm stuck at logging config.

I have this config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    ​
    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <!-- Example for logging into the build folder of your project -->
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="C://tmp//test"/>​

    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr([${springAppName:-},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]){yellow} %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

    <!-- Appender to log to console -->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ​
    <!-- Appender to log to file in a JSON format -->
    <appender name="logstash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}.json</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.json.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                <pattern>
                    <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "severity": "%level",
                        "service": "${springAppName:-}",
                        "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                        "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                        "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                        "exportable": "%X{X-Span-Export:-}",
                        "baggage": "%X{key:-}",
                        "pid": "${PID:-}",
                        "thread": "%thread",
                        "class": "%logger{40}",
                        "rest": "%message"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ​
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But when I check file I'm missing traceId and spanId. Here is the example:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-01-12T17:31:51.861Z","severity":"INFO","service":"kz-report","pid":"25248","thread":"http-nio-9089-exec-1","class":"c.k.r.s.impl.ExaminationServiceImpl","rest":"User with ID 1 and name Nemanja is fetching examination by ID 2"}
```

This is snippet from pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Not sure how to proceed here, I've been reading docs and stack overflow posts but still couldn't find any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you have an example with logback logstash https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spring-cloud-workshops/blob/master/fraud-detection/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml

Comment: That is configuration for LogstashTcpSocketAppender when I adjusted it to be RollingFileAppender and added <file> tag to point to file I have still same result, empty values for trace, span, parent and exportable.

Comment: Which version of sleuth are you using?

Comment: I added spring-cloud-starter-zipkin version 2.2.6.RELEASE. That dependency pulls in spring-cloud-starter-sleuth with same version. Do I need 3.0.0. version for this to work ?

Comment: You can check also this https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps

Comment: I've bumped into this few days ago, still no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

hi the notation like "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-} does not work anymore you should use something like below:

```
 <appender name="logstash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOG_FILE}.json</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.json.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                <providers>
                    <timestamp>
                        <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                    </timestamp>
                    <pattern>
                        <pattern>
                            {
                            "timestamp": "@timestamp",
                            "severity": "%level",
                            "service": "${springAppName:-}",
                            "trace": "%X{traceId:-}",
                            "span": "%X{spanId:-}",
                            "pid": "${PID:-}",
                            "thread": "%thread",
                            "class": "%logger{40}",
                            "rest": "%message"
                            }
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>
                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
```

for more details please refers to the official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.3/reference/html/project-features.html#features-log-integration-json-logback) it work fro me in one my app on spring boot 2.5.6